# Jquery return false on form is actually submitting

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I need two inputs to not submit when "enter" is hit and do a different action, so I capture that two fields enter key press and return false, but the form is submitting anyway. Why?

```
@model  Venta

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Venta</h2>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Venta", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal col-md-12" id="DivForm">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Codigo_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Codigo_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Codigo_)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-5 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nombre_, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre_)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Agregar Stock" class="btn btn-default btn-primary btn-block" />
        </div>
    </div>

    //More filds here

}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#DivForm #Codigo_, #DivForm #Nombre_").bind('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) { // 13 is for enter key
                alert(); // Do something else
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I'm an in the first two fields, which are the two I'm talking about, I get the alert() and **also** the form is submitted. The "return false" is not working.

Comment: Have a look into the event.preventDefault() method too. May help

Answer (score 0):

Changing `keyup` to `keypress` solves the issue.